# Literal eval of Python object from command-line arg

Tags: python

I have a slightly messy pipeline whereby a Python script takes in some parameters from a user, stored internally as a dictionary:

```
{'robot': 'A', 'hours': 24, 'stations': [15, 17, 21], 'log': False}
```

and appends its string representation to a command to be run in a container

```
python robot.py {'robot': 'A', 'hours': 24, 'stations': [15, 17, 21], 'log': False}
```

In `robot.py` (inside the container), I'd like to parse it like this:

```
import sys
from ast import literal_eval


if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
    do_stuff(params)
```

Currently this fails because of parsing errors, as Python attempts to split up the input in some way.

Two questions:

- is this a *horrible* idea? (If so, what should I do instead?)
- if not, how can I `literal_eval` the dict as one argument? I expect to get lists, booleans, strings, ints, etc. as params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to quote the argument, as the shell will do all manner of processing before `python` even runs (and most of that will probably just produce a syntax error):

```
python robot.py "{'robot': 'A', 'hours': 24, 'stations': [15, 17, 21], 'log': False}"
```

Second, just because the script is *written* in Python doesn't mean the input has to be valid Python code. Use a language-agnostic format like JSON for these applications.

```
python robot.py '{"robot": "A", "hours": 24, "stations": [15, 17, 21], "log": False}'
```

with your code using the `json` module rather than the `ast` module.

```
import sys
import json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    do_stuff(params)
```

Comment: That's clever, it never occurred to me use `json` to parse a generic dictionary-as-a-string.

Comment: That's pretty much the *raison d'être* for JSON. It lets you encode/decode data structures the same way regardless of the source or target language.

Comment: (Being a lowest common denominator, of course, you may have to do some post-processing of the resulting data structure in Python. For example, JSON doesn't have a native date type; you would specify a string, then parse it using the `datetime` module.)

Answer (score 2):

> Currently this fails because of parsing errors, as Python attempts to split up the input in some way.

No; the input is split up by your shell, before Python ever receives it.

> is this a horrible idea?

Probably; you could probably come up with a scheme that lets users specify arbitrary data on the command line, working around standard shell parsing and following standard conventions for arguments, but it sounds like a lot of work - for both you and the user. As shown  in the other answer, it's also possible on the command line to quote the data and have it passed as a single token - but this gets unwieldy very quickly.

> (If so, what should I do instead?)

You could have the user supply the name of a preferences file on the command line, and open, read and parse that. I would recommend that you use the JSON format (with built-in support from the standard library `json` module) rather than expecting Python literals.

Or if there are only a few options such as shown, you could follow standard command-line conventions. Your input line might look something like `robot.py A --hours=24 --stations=15:17:21 --log` (omitting `log` when no logging should be done). The standard library `argparse` module can help with parsing that sort of thing, although you'd have to make sense of the `stations` string yourself.

Comment: I started off using argparse, but once I got to arrays I figured `eval`ing would be simpler.